# React TextField loses focus after key press

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a login/signup page but the TextField loses focus every time I press a key. The solution to this was to use `defaultValue` instead of `value` but then the state would stop updating.

```
const UserAuth = () => {
  const [switchForm, setSwitchForm] = useState(false)
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleEmail = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handlePassword = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
     console.log("email and pass", email, password);
     console.log("login");

  };
  const Login = () => {
    return (
      <div className="login-div">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <p className="login-text">Email</p>
          <TextField
            key="email"
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
            className="text-field"
            onChange={handleEmail}
            value={email}
          />
          <p className="login-text">Password</p>
          <TextField
            key="password"
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Password"
            variant="outlined"
            className="text-field"
            onChange={handlePassword}
            value={password}
          />

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            className="login-button"
            onClick={() => handleSubmit()}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
          <p>
            Don't have an account?{" "}
            <p
              className="switch-form"
              onClick={() => {
                setSwitchForm(false);
              }}
            >
              Sign up
            </p>
          </p>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const UserAuth = () => {
  // ...
  const Login = () => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This `Login` component is defined *inside* the UserAuth component. So what will happen is that every time `UserAuth` renders, A new `Login` function is created. It may have the same text as the previous function, but react just checks `===` and so will think that it is a different type of component. Since they are different types of components, react unmounts the old one and mounts the new one. A newly mounted input field does not have focus.

The fix is to define your components just once; move `Login` outside of `UserAuth`. This does mean you'll have to pass some values as props instead of using closure variables. email, password, handleEmail, handlePassword, and handleSubmit will all need to be props.

Comment: That seems to work but how do I use states like switchForm and pass it amongst components? I've also got <SignUp /> which would toggle with the Button in Login component but now that they're out of UserAuth, they would be inaccessible

Comment: You use props to pass things between components. So for example, `UserAuth` will have the state `const [switchForm, setSwitchForm] = useState(false)`, and then it will pass it to the Login component like `<Login switchForm={switchForm} />`. If you need to pass setSwitchForm as a prop, you can do that too `<Login switchForm={switchForm} setSwitchForm={setSwitchForm} />`